# Populating a hibernate/jpa MySql datasource on JBoss startup

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss

In other words, making JBoss run a SQL script file or bean immediately on startup.

I want to re-populate my database each time it gets re-constructed when I re-launch my app. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending about JBoss version (Singleton being introduced in Java EE 6) you can maybe use [Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) bean annotated with [Startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html) and execute these operations in [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) method.

Something like following:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class Initializer {
    @PostConstruct
    public void populate() {
        //initialize database here
    }
}
```

According specification Singleton bean is instantiated once for each JVM - consequently usage in cluster can bring surprises.

Comment: Thanks!

Completely out of curiousity, is there a way to do it without EJB's? Like edit the standalone file to automatically run an sql script? Or use JDBC? I'm using JBoss 7.1 btw.